# Htmltext in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to add a **multicolor** (maybe html) text to a clickable android listview.

For example:
    te**s**t
Is that possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: in my app i have to display some text which is in multible colors, so i have {green}aaasd{red}sada... And I want to display this text in a listview, i can´t take a normal view because i need each element to be clickable on its own

Comment: You would need a custom Adapter for that. Not possible with the default one.

Comment: Yes, but which element should i use for it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

Use The **Spannable** API.

A tuto explain you in details how to do it: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177

Just some code for understand:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView );
Spannable spannable = (Spannable)textView.getText();
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
spannable.setSpan( boldSpan, 41, 52, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use HTML directly quite easily. Here is an example with color, small text and bold text:

```
String styledText = "<font color='#666666'>grey text</font><small>small text</small><b>bold text</b>";
exampleEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```